# Getting an error in values-v21 stylebase.xml

Tags: android

Target version and compile version are 16 but I am getting an error in values-v21 stylebase.xml. How to resolve this error?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 65 Android AAPT Problem
The end-tag for element type "style" must end with a '>' delimiter. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 45 Android XML Format Problem
```

Comment: please post Your related style xml

Comment: Corrected title and question details.